# How to change the main branch to master on github command line?

Tags: git, github

[image: the image shows what it actually looks on command line]

I'm learning to use GitHub, I found that my default branch is `main` although I've changed it to `master` using my account in GitHub  website but it still appears on the command line as `main`. It has caused many problems in the authentication process in every `git push` command, I want to change the main branch to be (master => origin) like usual. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Not only do you have to change the name of the branch in your remote, but you'll have to change it locally as well: `git branch -m master`. Then, you'll need to set `origin/master` as the corresponding remote branch: `git push -u origin master`.

Answer (score 31):

So far, you have only renamed your remote branch from `main` to `master`. So, to  change your local branch name, first, checkout branch `main` (if you aren't already on it):

```
$ git checkout main
```

Next, rename branch `main` to branch `master`:

```
$ git branch -m master
```

Then, set `origin/master` to track your local branch `master`:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score -7):

the command is: *git branch -m main master*.
this is also a link to understand it more: https://stevenmortimer.com/5-steps-to-change-github-default-branch-from-master-to-main/